# Kotlin equivalent of MainActivity.java handling incoming intents from external applications for use in Flutter

Tags: java, android, flutter, kotlin, android-intent

The documentation for "How do I handle incoming intents from external applications in Flutter?" at https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/flutter-for/android-devs#how-do-i-handle-incoming-intents-from-external-applications-in-flutter has code for the MainActivity written in Java. Yet there is no Kotlin equivalent but my Flutter project builds Kotlin files. Hence, **all I need is the Kotlin equivalent for the following Java code** (or at least as close to it as possible, I'm sure I can figure out the rest):

```
package com.example.shared;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel;
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity;
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;

public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {

  private String sharedText;
  private static final String CHANNEL = "app.channel.shared.data";

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    String type = intent.getType();

    if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
      if ("text/plain".equals(type)) {
        handleSendText(intent); // Handle text being sent
      }
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
      GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine);

      new MethodChannel(flutterEngine.getDartExecutor().getBinaryMessenger(), CHANNEL)
              .setMethodCallHandler(
                      (call, result) -> {
                          if (call.method.contentEquals("getSharedText")) {
                              result.success(sharedText);
                              sharedText = null;
                          }
                      }
              );
  }

  void handleSendText(Intent intent) {
    sharedText = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
  }
}
```

(I could learn Java but zero of my work involve Java until now, so it doesn't seem efficient to learn Java just to translate this one file.)

Comment: Just paste your code in the IDE, it will automatically convert to Kotlin. Android Studio gives that option at least.

Comment: @che10, thanks! That gave me a good lead to have finally solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @che10's hint to use Android Studio's Jave to Kotlin converter (https://developer.android.com/kotlin/add-kotlin#convert), I was able to convert to a baseline that was almost compilable. The compile errors were enough clues to tell me what were the remaining touchups I had to do. The result is below:

```
package com.example.shared

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle

import androidx.annotation.NonNull

import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant

class MainActivity : FlutterActivity() {
    private var sharedText: String? = null
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val intent: Intent = getIntent()
        val action: String? = intent.getAction()
        val type: String? = intent.getType()
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEND == action && type != null) {
            if ("text/plain" == type) {
                handleSendText(intent) // Handle text being sent
            }
        }
    }

    override fun configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine)
        MethodChannel(flutterEngine.getDartExecutor().getBinaryMessenger(), CHANNEL)
            .setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->
                if (call.method.contentEquals("getSharedText")) {
                    result.success(sharedText)
                    sharedText = null
                }
            }
    }

    fun handleSendText(intent: Intent) {
        sharedText = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT)
    }

    companion object {
        private const val CHANNEL = "app.channel.shared.data"
    }
}
```